# After Ctrl+Alt+F3 during login, Ctrl+Alt+F7 only blackscreens

Tags: kubuntu, 19.10

I'm using Kubuntu 19.10. During the login screen, I've pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to fire up the terminal.

According to multiple articles, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> should return me to the previous, GUI-based login screen after I'm finished with the terminal.

Instead, the entire screen goes black, with only an `_` blinking in the upper left. I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> again,

How can I remedy this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment of the virtual consoles has changed since Ubuntu 17.10. Virtual console 1 is assigned to GDM. Virtual console 2 will contain your running desktop if you were logged in. Virtual console 3 and higher are terminal consoles.

In previous versions, all graphical sessions were on Virtual console 7.

Answer (score 2):

`CTRL+ALT+F1` did the trick, returned to Plasma login screen correctly.